# Sailsjs fiber integration

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, fiber

Im trying to integrate SailsJS with synchronize, which is based on fibers.

http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html

As commented on other fiber libraries, I added a custom middleware to create a new fiber per the request.

```
var sync = require('synchronize');
...
...
sincronized: function (req, res, next) {
   sync.fiber(next);
}
```

The middleware is executing I can confirm via a console.
But then when I try to do anything fiber related, such as sync.defer() in one of my controllers, I do get an exception.

error: Error getting xxxxxx Error: no current Fiber, defer can't be used without Fiber!

As sailsjs is based in express, adding this middleware should be enough, although I have no idea what I might be missing.

As a side comment, if I create a fiber inside the controller method itself, everything works as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install fiber? and did you require the module in your script?

Comment: Hello Brandon, yes, as indicated, when I create the fiber inside the controller everything works as expected.

Comment: What do the fiber docs say to do?

Comment: For express, exactly what I am doing.
Wrap with a fiber the callback in the middleware, which is basically my code.
You mean for adding fibers to all express request? or in what sense you mean the documentation?